# Displaying data from multiple tables in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery

**Question**

I want to display a combination of DATA from different tables. In this case all combinations of food and drink, which have not been ordered so far.

**My database tables**

**Customer_order**

```
Orderno(PK)  DateOrd    DateReq    Address
O00001       03-Apr-11  07-Apr-11  Union St
O00002       05-Apr-11  01-May-11  St. Andrew St.
O00003       12-Apr-11  27-Apr-11  Garthdee
O00004       12-Apr-11  17-Apr-11  Union St.
```

**Dish**

```
Dishid(PK)  DishName         Vegetarian   Price
D0001       Pasta bake       yes           6.00
D0002       Fish pie         No            9.00
D0003       Steak and chips  No           14.00
D0004       Stuffed peppers  yes          11.50
D0005       Ham and rice     No            7.25
D0006       Lamb curry       No            8.50
```

**Drink**

```
Drinkid(PK)  DrinkName    DrinkType  Price
DR0001       Water        soft        1.00
DR0002       Coffee       hot         1.70
DR0003       Wine         alcoholic   3.00
DR0004       Beer         alcoholic   2.30
DR0005       tea          hot         1.50
```

**Food_order**

```
Food_orderno(PK)  Orderno(FK)  Dishid(FK)  NPortions
FO00001           O00001       D0003         6
FO00002           O00001       D0001         4
FO00003           O00001       D0004         3
FO00004           O00002       D0001        10
FO00005           O00002       D0002        10
FO00006           O00003       D0002        35
FO00007           O00004       D0002        23
```

**Drink_order**

```
Drinkorderid(PK)  Orderid(FK)  Drinkid(FK)  N_units
DO00001           O00001       DR0001       13
DO00002           O00001       DR0002       13
DO00003           O00001       DR0004       13
DO00004           O00002       DR0001       20
DO00005           O00002       DR0003       20
DO00006           O00002       DR0004       15
DO00007           O00003       DR0002       35
DO00008           O00004       DR0001       23
DO00009           O00004       DR0003       15
DO00010           O00004       DR0004       15
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aocy7.jpg

**Queries tried so far**

```
select distinct d.dish_name, dr.drink_name
from Dish d, Drink dr, Food_order fo, Drink_order dro, Customer_order co
where co.orderno = fo.orderno
  AND co.orderno = dro.orderno
order by dish_name, drink_name;

select d.dish_name, dr.drink_name
from Dish d, Drink dr, Food_order fo, Drink_order dro, Customer_order co
where co.orderno = fo.orderno
  AND co.orderno = dro.orderno
group by d.dish_name, dr.drink_name;

select distinct d.dish_name, dr.drink_name
from Dish d, Drink dr, Food_order fo, Drink_order dro, Customer_order co
where d.dishid = fo.DISHID
  AND dr.DRINKID = dro.DRINKID
  AND fo.ORDERNO = dro.ORDERNO
group by d.dish_name, dr.drink_name;

select distinct d.dish_name, dr.drink_name
from dish d, drink dr, food_order fo, drink_order do
where fo.ORDERNO = do.ORDERNO
group by d.dish_name, dr.drink_name;
```

Comment: I am not totally sure what you want: if you mean you want to list all combinations of a dish and a drink which have not occurred together in any customer order, perhaps you could add that to the description. Otherwise, please say what you do want.

Comment: I have the feeling that you are not clear about the need to join all tables on some key to avoid a combinatorial explosion, and also that you do not seem to have tried to express _a combination of food and drink which have not been ordered_ in your `WHERE`-clauses.

Comment: Yes your right. Thats exactly what i want to display. And you have a right feeling. Im not sure what im doing thats why im here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to return, what you are asking for:

```
SELECT
  Dish.DishName,
  Dish.Dishid,
  Drink.DrinkName,
  Drink.Drinkid
FROM Dish
JOIN
  (SELECT
      Dishid
      , Drinkid
    FROM Dish
    CROSS JOIN Drink
    MINUS
    (SELECT
      Dishid
      , Drinkid
    FROM Food_order
    CROSS JOIN Drink_order
    WHERE Food_order.Orderno = Drink_order.Orderid
    )
  ) NotOrderedTogether
  ON Dish.Dishid = NotOrderedTogether.Dishid
JOIN Drink
  ON NotOrderedTogether.Drinkid = Drink.Drinkid
ORDER BY Dishname, Drinkname
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/42a9b0/1).

As pointed out in the comments, the result set is going to explode, if you add large(r) numbers of food and beverages. In that case, it would probably make sense to apply the `MINUS` first to dishes and drinks respectively, and to apply the `CROSS JOIN` to the least possible number of records.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Well done, ur a LEGEND! It does exactly what I want it do. BUT, I dont quite get why use joins. Like if I want to extract data from different tables in the same database I would just use

For Example
SELECT d.DISH_name, dr.DRINK_name
FROM Dish d, Drink dr

Comment: `FROM Dish D, Food_order FO WHERE D.dishid = FO.dishid` is a join as well. It's just a different syntax - and Oracle did in old(er) versions not support the explicit `JOIN` style. The explicit style is to many people more readable. Most of the time, there is no difference in the result set - placement of conditions could have an effect, e.g., if non-equi joins come into play.

Comment: Thank you very much again! Perfect solution. perfect explanation! 5 stars.

Comment: My pleasure. BTW: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (which requires the [privilege to vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)), [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), and (more detailed) [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ;-)

Comment: Im not sure. Im a real noob on this forum, and ask questions not very often. This was the first time EVER I found a useful answer to my question on this forum.

Comment: Never mind. Let me re-phrase: If it is helpful to you, please, consider to *accept* the answer or/and to vote for it (but the latter does require minimum 15 reputation at this time). - The links above do provide more detail/context.  ;-)

Comment: There you go, I accepted it. However I dont have enough rep to vote :/